# Annotating a schematic in Altium

Tags: altium

I'm trying to annotate a Schematic project in Altium, my aim is to get, for example, in the 1st sheet : C101. C102 R101 and so on , in the 2nd something like : C201  C202 L201.

I've been trying in vain to do that.So I've decide annotate each sheet alone(Not the whole project), but this turns out to be tricky. Here's what I get :

[image]

So as you can the proposed names are  the same as the current ones !

any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for board level annotate here (you would need that with a multi channel design) and you're already on the right track.

Where you selected 100, assign start designators for all sheets: 100,200,300,400 ...; also check the checkbox next to it (as you did with the 100).

Not click on Reset Designators, which will remove already assigned Designators. Then click Update Changes List, and finally, Create the ECO list (which will then effectively assign them).

Done.

Answer (score 2):

I believe while in the Schematic editor you can go to Tools --> Board Level Annotate:

[image]

In the new window hit the button that says "Annotate Options":

[image]

and for the "Naming Scheme" you would use the keyword for the component prefix ("U", "R", "C", etc), followed by the sheet number keyword, followed by the keyword for the component index (1, 2, 3, etc). I believe in your case this would be `$ComponentPrefix$SheetNumber$ComponentIndex`.

[image]

More information about these keywords can be found in the [Altium documentation](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Understanding+Design+Annotation), a little over half way down the page.

Then click the "Annotate" --> "Annotate All" buttons:

[image]
[image]

And this is what the result will look like:

[image]

The project I used to create this example doesn't have multiple sheets, but you can trust that on sheet 2, the component indexes would start with 2 instead of 1 (in the above image).

Using this method, U24 (for example) on sheet 1 would have the designator `U124`, R15 on sheet 2 would have the designator `R215`, and so on.